# UDP over NAT fail

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp, p2p

I have this code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <thread>
#include "STUN.h"

bool do_work = true;
using namespace std;

void receiver(int sock) {
    //boost::asio::io_service& s
    sockaddr_in from_adr;
    std::cout << "START: receiver\n";
    size_t blen = 2048;
    char * buf = new char[blen];
    unsigned slen = sizeof(from_adr);

    if (recvfrom(sock, (void *) buf, blen, 0, (sockaddr*) &from_adr, &slen)
            < 0) {
        std::cout << "Recv problem\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    do_work = false;
    std::cout << "STOP: receiver\n";
}

void sender(sockaddr_in * to, int sock) {
    std::cout << "START: sender\n";

    while (do_work) {
        if (sendto(sock, "OK", 3, 0, (sockaddr*) to, sizeof(sockaddr)) < 0) {
            std::cout << "SEND PROBLEM\n";
            return;
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    std::cout << "RECEIVED!!!\n\n\n";
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: udp-flood-test <port>\n";
        return 1;
    }
    ippd stun_adr;
    stun_adr.addr = "64.233.161.127";
    stun_adr.port = 19302;
    STUN stun(stun_adr);

    std::string eip;
    uint16_t epp;

    uint16_t lp = std::atoi(argv[1]);

    ippd sti = stun.getSTUN(lp);
    std::cout << "External address: " << sti.addr << ":" << sti.port << "\n";
    std::cout << "Internal address: " << "127.0.0.1:" << lp << "\n";
    std::cout << "Write external ip: ";
    std::cin >> eip;
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Write external port: ";
    std::cin >> epp;
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "OK. I'll send data to " << eip << ":" << epp << "\n";

    int m_sock;                     // дескриптор сокета
    sockaddr_in m_addr;             // переменная адреса интерфейса
    std::string my_addr = "0.0.0.0";             // Адрес локального интерфейса

    /* Создание сокета и присвоение значения дескриптору сокета для UDP пакетов
     * PF_INET    - IP protocol family
     * SOCK_DGRAM - Raw protocol interface */
    if ((m_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Обнуляем переменную m_addr и забиваем её нужными значениями */
    memset(&m_addr, 0, sizeof(m_addr));
    m_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;  // обязательно AF_INET!
    m_addr.sin_port = htons(lp); // 0 - выдать порт автоматом
    /* Переводим адрес в нужный нам формат */
    if (inet_aton(my_addr.c_str(), &m_addr.sin_addr) == 0) {
        perror("inet_aton");
        close(m_sock);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Биндим сокет */
    if (bind(m_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &m_addr, sizeof(m_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        close(m_sock);
        return -1;
    }
    sockaddr_in to_addr;
    memset(&to_addr, 0, sizeof(to_addr));
    to_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    to_addr.sin_port = htons(epp);
    if (inet_aton(eip.c_str(), &to_addr.sin_addr) == 0) {
        perror("inet_aton");
        close(m_sock);
        return -1;
    }

    std::thread inp(receiver, m_sock);
    std::thread oup(sender, &to_addr, m_sock);

    oup.detach();
    inp.detach();
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's a simple test program to get external ip and port over STUN and send data from peer A to peer B (and from B to A).

So program works fine if I set IPs and ports as 127.0.0.1:port or local_network_ip:port.

If I set IP received from STUN server peer A will send UDP packets to peer B. And B will send packets to A. But A and B haven't any incoming packets. In Wireshark I can see outgoing packets too, but no incoming.

Network connection diagram:

A (pc with active test program) - NAT (home router) - ... - NAT (internet provider) - internet - NAT (another internet provider) - ... - NAT (another home router) - B (another pc with active test program)

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?..

Where can I find a problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the double-NAT is killing you.

Comment: @RonMaupin, yes, you're right. Solution:  make port forwarding in home router before trying to accept data.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in double NAT. Home routers (from network diagram) rejecting packets if you have no configured port forwarding.

Follow this steps to work over double NAT:

1. select local port to receive packets.
2. try to bind port. (if failed then return to step 1)
3. configure port forwarding in home router using NAT-PMP or UPnP IGD.
4. use STUN to get your external IP and port
5. share data from step 4 to another program instance
6. send and/or receive UDP packets

Comment: you should look into hole punching